# Grab or pick up?

Tags: difference, colloquial-language

1. Gaming on consoles is more convenient than computers. You can just pick up/grab your controller and start playing right away.
2. Can you grab/pick up some chips from the grocery store?

Do 'grab' and 'pick up' mean the same thing? I've heard that 'grab' means to pick something up quickly.

Comment: Using [**grab**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/grab) suggests rudeness or haste. "I'll just grab something to eat *(because I don't have time for a proper meal)*," or "I grabbed the controller from my brother *(because he had been playing long enough)*."

Comment: Does that mean 'pick up' is more polite and doesn't suggest that you need to hurry?

Comment: In you second example does grab suggests something like 'snatch?' Since it sounds like you didn't only take it from him, you took it away from him.